# How to groupBy groupBy?

Tags: scala, group-by

I need to map through a `List[(A,B,C)]` to produce an html report. Specifically, a

```
List[(Schedule,GameResult,Team)]
```

Schedule contains a gameDate property that I need to group by on to get a

```
Map[JodaTime, List(Schedule,GameResult,Team)]
```

which I use to display gameDate table row headers. Easy enough:

```
val data = repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_._1.gameDate)
```

Now the tricky bit (for me) is, how to further refine the grouping in order to enable mapping through the game results as pairs? To clarify, each GameResult consists of a team's "version" of the game (i.e. score, location, etc.), sharing a common Schedule gameID with the opponent team.

Basically, I need to display a game result outcome on one row as:

```
3 London Dragons vs. Paris Frogs 2
```

Grouping on gameDate let's me do something like:

```
data.map{case(date,games) =>
  // game date row headers
  <tr><td>{date.toString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}</td></tr>

  // print out game result data rows
  games.map{case(schedule,result, team)=>
    ...
    // BUT (result,team) slice is ungrouped, need grouped by Schedule gameID
  }
}
```

In the old version of the existing application (PHP) I used to

```
for($x = 0; $x < $this->gameCnt; $x = $x + 2) {...}
```

but I'd prefer to refer to variable names and not the come-back-later-wtf-is-that-inducing:

```
games._._2(rowCnt).total games._._3(rowCnt).name games._._1(rowCnt).location games._._2(rowCnt+1).total games._._3(rowCnt+1).name
```

maybe zip or double up for(t1 <- data; t2 <- data) yield(?) or something else entirely will do the trick.  Regardless, there's a concise solution, just not coming to me right now...

Comment: why not just do another groupBy? games.groupBy(_._1.gameID)

Comment: because it does not pair the games on gameID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your requirements, but it seems to me that all you need is an additional groupBy:

```
repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_._1.gameDate).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._1.gameID))
```

The result will be of type:

```
Map[JodaTime, Map[GameId, List[(Schedule,GameResult,Team)]]]
```

(where `GameId` is the type of the return type of `Schedule.gameId`)

**Update:** if you want the results as pairs, then pattern matching is your friend, as shown by Arjan. This would give us:

```
val byDate = repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_._1.gameDate)
val data = byDate.mapValues(_.groupBy(_._1.gameID).mapValues{ case List((sa, ra, ta), (sb, rb, tb)) => (sa, (ta, ra), (tb, rb)))
```

This time the result is of type:

```
Map[JodaTime, Iterable[ (Schedule,(Team,GameResult),(Team,GameResult))]]
```

Note that this will throw a `MatchError` if there are not exactly 2 entries with the same gameId. In real code you will definitely want to check for this case.

Comment: actually does not work, need the games paired, I hacked it together with zipWithIndex

Comment: Then I suggest that you update your question to be more explicit about what you need, and then post (and accept) your own answer.

Comment: I'm going to give you the nod (again) Regis, as you provided the original solution first. The match against paired result teams is "case List(a,b)=>" since I'm now working with case class instead of Tuple3. Scala continues to amaze, thanks for the concise solution! BTW, to preserve ordering on the game date I had to resort to ListMap and this hard-to-grok-later 1-liner: "ListMap (repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_.schedule.gameDate).mapValues(_.groupBy(_.schedule.id).values).toList.sortBy(_._1.ms):_* )" where ms is an alias for JodaTime's getMillis()

Comment: yeah, that's the case match warning I was talking about. Will always be 2 teams, game result cannot exist in database without 2 unique participant teams

Answer (score 1):

Ok a soultion from Régis Jean-Gilles:

```
val data = repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_._1.gameDate).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._1.gameID))
```

You said it was not correct, maybe you just didnt use it the right way?
Every List in the result is a pair of games with the same GameId.
You could pruduce html like that:

```
data.map{case(date,games) =>
  // game date row headers
  <tr><td>{date.toString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}</td></tr>

  // print out game result data rows
  games.map{case (gameId, List((schedule, result, team), (schedule, result, team))) =>
    ...
  }
}
```

And since you dont need a gameId, you can return just the paired games:

```
val data = repo.games.findAllByDate(fooDate).groupBy(_._1.gameDate).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._1.gameID).values)
```

Tipe of result is now:

```
Map[JodaTime, Iterable[List[(Schedule,GameResult,Team)]]]
```

Every list again a pair of two games with the same GameId

Comment: +1, sh*t that is really good ;-) Thought that groupBy was filtering down the List in "Map[JodaDate, List[...]]" much like a database query group by, and returning a single game per game date.  Not the case, must have been my errant attempts to create a pairing.

Comment: now to sort out the fact that groupBy on gameDate creates a Map which has no guarantee re: ordering (read: db query order by gameDate bye-bye). Can convert to a ListMap for that. Anyway...as for the pairing, I get a compiler warning, but this works: "games.map{ case(List(a,b))=> ..." to produce game result scoring row (nicer, IMO, than "map{ x=> x(0).total x(0).name ... x(1).total")